# Using AJAX and python

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb, python-2.7

So I'm trying to use this web framework Tangelo.  In my javascript I use AJAX and I'm trying to get the result of some Python script using AJAX.  The python queries a mongodb, but I don't know if the path I specify is correct in AJAX or if I'm missing something.  Can someone provide some help, or a better method for doing this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "service/findRecords/" + database + "/mydb/questions",
    data: {search_keyword : srch_kwrd},
    dataType: "script",
    type: "GET",
    sucess: function(rtn){
        console.log("I GOT TO THE FUNCTION IN AJAX");
        results = rtn;
        d3.select("#myapp-content")
        .html(results);
        d3.select("#myapp-content")
        .html(rtn);
    },
    complete: function(){console.log("Finish ajax");
                        console.log("Show me potato salad:  "+"service/findRecords/" + database + "/mydb/questions");}
});
```

Sorry didn't explain.  The database variable I set to both the string 'mongo' and 'localhost:8080', but that didn't do anything.  In my return statement I just want to return the results of the python script.  Which is in the service directory as seen above.  Its written like this:

```
import datetime
import itertools
import pymongo
import tangelo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
mydb = client.mydb
question_collection = mydb.questions
search_results = []

#return a list of json objects which represent rows of a database
#i.e. [{1:2},{3:4}]
def run(host, database, collection, search_keyword = None):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AJAX to talk to MongoDB, you need to go through the MongoDB's REST API, as documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/)

The URL should look something like `http://localhost:28017`. From your code, it appears your url looks something like `service/findRecords/localhost:8080/mydb/questions`, which is of the wrong shape, and referring to the wrong port.

To debug why the requests from AJAX are failing, you could try using Fiddler.

Comment: I'm actually trying to go through python to query mongo, so I need to use findRecords (which is my python function name, sorry for not mention that).